# How can I use this extension method in a linq to entities query using query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-query-syntax

I am creating a query to return some data from a database.
I am passing in a list of ids that I want to filter on. If the filter list is null or empty I want to return all the things.

I have an extension method that lets me do this
`query` is an `IQueryable`, `Ids` is a list of nullable ints (don't ask!) `ListHasElements` is a method that returns true if the list is non-null and has something in it.

```
 var filteredList = query.WhereIf(ListHasElements(Ids), s => Ids.Contains(s.Id.Value));
```

However when I build `query` I use my prefered query syntax

```
var query = from a in dbContext.as
            join b in dbContext.bs on a.Id.ToString() equals b.Id
            join cin dbContext.cs on b.Id equals c.Id into bcJoin
            from items in bcJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where b.Sent >= fromDate
            where b.Sent <= toDate
            select new{a=a.thing, b=b.thingy, q=items.q,Id=a.Id}
```

Then I have to insert the initial line to do my magic WhereIf filter. and finally a further select to group by and create my output object (code not shown!)

The extension method looks like this.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition,
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

Can I use this method directly in my query syntax query?

Comment: The method `WhereIf` has a parameter `condition` of type `bool`. How are you passing `Ids`  which is a list?

Comment: I simplified my real code a bit too far :) One second!

Comment: Youve hit upon one reason I much prefer the extension method syntax to the query syntax.

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter? `dbContext.as`? `dbContext.bs`?

Comment: Why do people like so much the query syntax? I find it a lot more difficult to understand.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Joins are _much_ cleaner in query syntax.  Adding intermediate results with `let` is handy in some cases as well.  That's about it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  The compiler takes well-known query syntax keywords and converts them to method syntax behind-the-scenes.  It knows nothing of your custom extension and thus has no equivalent in query syntax.  Note that other "built-in" linq functions have no query syntax equivalent:

- `Skip`
- `Count`
- `Take`
- `Single`
- `FirstOrDefault`
- `Max`
- etc.

Although I would note that your extension is basically equivalent to

```
where !condition || predicate(b)
```

Comment: My answer works just fine, and uses his .WhereIf in his query.

Comment: @RobertMcKee but not as the question asks.

Comment: @RobertMcKee What do you do if `predicate` depends on the results of the join instead of just the original set?

Comment: It answers the question he asked `Can I use this method directly in my query syntax query?`, which is yes.  I used the method in his query syntax query, and it gives the results he wants.  Seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: @DStanley That wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx):

> Some queries must be expressed as method calls

This is one of those cases. Even some of their own extension methods must be called via method syntax. For example, `Count`.

Answer (score -1):

YES!

```
var query = from a in dbContext.as.WhereIf(ListHasElements(Ids), s => Ids.Contains(s.Id.Value))
        join b in dbContext.bs on a.Id.ToString() equals b.Id
        join cin dbContext.cs on b.Id equals c.Id into bcJoin
        from items in bcJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where b.Sent >= fromDate
        where b.Sent <= toDate
        select new{a=a.thing, b=b.thingy, q=items.q,Id=a.Id}
```

My test code (Listings is a table with an Id field):

```
void Main()
{
   var list=new int []{1,2,3,4};
   var query=from l in Listings.WhereIf(ListHasElements(list),s=>list.Contains(s.Id))
   select l;
   query.Dump();
}
public bool ListHasElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> it)
{
    return it.Any();
}

public static class Ext {
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition,
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
    }
}
```

Comment: The filtering happens at the end, not the beginning.  You're also not doing that in query syntax, you're using method syntax.  (You're just avoiding creation of a second variable.)

Comment: I used the method in his query syntax.  Apparently he has no issues doing so since is using `.ToString` and `.DefaultIfEmtpy` which are both methods in his otherwise query syntax.  As to doing the filtering at the end or beginning, it makes no difference in the results of his query.  I used it in his query, and it gives the results you would expect.